# How to validate the input chaged by inspect element?

Tags: c#, validation

I am using C# mvc in that application I have one TextBox with read only property and using regular expression for restricting special character. It will work fine for getting input (without readonly) but when View the details in one page at that time TextBox will be read only.

If I change the value using inspect element the exception will raise with error message for that field

I am using this code to validate

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\-]+$", ErrorMessage = "Special Characters are not allowed")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have one TextBox with read only property and using regular expression for restricting special character. It will work fine for getting input (without readonly) but when View the details in one page at that time TextBox will be read only.

If I change the value using inspect element the exception will raise with error message for that field

In other words the regular expression is working fine when the user is filling out a form and it is only allowing the characters allowed by the regular expression. In another page, you display information, but for viewing purposes (readonly), and you are worried the user can change the readonly field using the browser devloper tool (inspect element). Therefore, you want the regular expression to prevent it.

**Always Validate on the server**

You should never trust input submitted in a web form. Even in the first case when you are allowing the user to edit the field, the user can turn off the regular expression. This is why you should validate again on the server side code.

In the second case, when you are simply displaying information, the user cannot submit it so if they go behind the scenes (developer tools) and change the field, then you should not worry about it. But if the change affects another item which can be submitted, then you need to validate that on the server side.

You should *always* and *always* check the web form input on the server side, even if you have already checked it on the client side. The user, if they are savvy, can even add more options to a drop-down, select item from it, and submit the form. Therefore, do not trust it.